# How to remove products linked to another store view?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In `Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product::collectRawData()` :

There is the following lines starting at line `904`:

```
$collection = $this->_getEntityCollection();
        foreach ($this->_storeIdToCode as $storeId => $storeCode) {
            $collection->setStoreId($storeId);
```

I would like to remove the products that are part of a specific store Code as it is causing duplicates during the export.

Is there perhaps a way to get the SQL query that puts the collection for a specific store view together?

**Update:**

I tried to find `catalog_product_entity_*` with `store_id != 0` but there were none.

I have found that from `Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Export\Product::collectRawData()` the data returned is an associative array.

Consisting of a product for each storeview.
Funny thing is that where there are just 4 attributes per storeview, it is emptied out by this method `$this->appendMultirowData($dataRow, $multirawData);` but there is a case where more than 4 attributes come back for the storeview and that creates the duplicate on the excel spreadsheet.

Example of array with 4 elements

```
array(4)
sku:"DLN-22083"
store_id:1
product_id:3485
product_link_id:"3485"
```

Example of an array with 10 elements

```
array(10)
description:"<p>My Desc</p>"
technical_specifications:"<ul><li>Red</li></ul>"
_store:"shs_en"
_attribute_set:"Dies"
_type:"simple"
sku:"DLN-14426"
store_id:1
product_id:3484
product_link_id:"3484"
```

So if I can stop there extra attributes from being added then the product won't be added to the spreadsheet

Comment: Found that this has to do with `html_entities` not being decoded. THis has been fixed in the latest magento.

Comment: Fixed in https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d0ed6ed907e1309cc1c1a1d81e25766de09e35e2 so should be fixed in `2.1.8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually products are not **directly** linked to any store view, but their **values** can be changed at **store view** level. So you can show different values for different store views.

For example, you have a product with the price **$200** in default store view. You can change **price** for another store view to **$100**, if you want. The **price** information is saved in the table `catalog_product_entity_decimal`.

If you look at the table, you will see that there is a **store_id** field in it. This field makes it possible for you to define different values for each **store view**.

`mysql> select * from catalog_product_entity_decimal;
+----------+--------------+----------+--------+----------+
| value_id | attribute_id | store_id | row_id | value    |
+----------+--------------+----------+--------+----------+
|        1 |           77 |        0 |      1 | 111.0000 |
|        2 |           77 |        0 |      3 |  11.0000 |
|        3 |           77 |        0 |      4 | 200.0000 |
|        4 |           77 |        0 |      5 | 200.0000 |
|        5 |           77 |        0 |      6 | 200.0000 |
|        6 |           77 |        0 |      7 | 200.0000 |
|        7 |           77 |        0 |      8 | 200.0000 |
|        8 |           77 |        0 |      9 | 200.0000 |
|        9 |           77 |        1 |      9 | 100.0000 |
+----------+--------------+----------+--------+----------+`

After all these explanation, let me show how to combine these values. First of all, you need to inject some dependencies in your constructor.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
)
{
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}
```

After that, you can run the following code block. This code block will combine a specific store view with the default one. The store view is stored in the variable `$storeViewId`.

```
// This is the specific store view id to be combined
$storeViewId = 1;
$resourceConnection = $this->resourceConnection;

// Get connection adapter
$connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();

// Get tables names
$tableProductEntityDatetime = $resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_datetime');
$tableProductEntityDecimal = $resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_decimal');
$tableProductEntityInt = $resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_int');
$tableProductEntityText = $resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_text');
$tableProductEntityVarchar = $resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_varchar');

$tableNames = [
    $tableProductEntityDatetime,
    $tableProductEntityInt,
    $tableProductEntityDecimal,
    $tableProductEntityText,
    $tableProductEntityVarchar
];
foreach ($tableNames as $tableName) {
    $rowsAttributes = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT `value_id`, `attribute_id`, `value` FROM `{$tableName}` WHERE `row_id` = :row_id AND `store_id` = :store_view_id", [
        'row_id' => $product->getRowId(),
        'store_view_id' => $storeViewId
    ]);
    foreach ($rowsAttributes as $row) {
        $connection->delete($tableName, "`value_id` = {$row['value_id']}");
        try {
            $connection->insert($tableName, [
                'attribute_id' => $row['attribute_id'],
                'store_id' => 0,
                'row_id' => $product->getRowId(),
                'value' => $row['value']
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Entry already created
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After export open CSV in Excel and filter any specific store so you get unique value. If your purpose is only for remove duplicate in export file